# How do I determine for given two rectangles A & B, with B having constant dimensions, that B is more than 50% inside A?

Tags: coordinate-systems, area

I have 2 rectangles in a 2D plane, only in the first quadrant with limit 2000 x 2000:

A (black) & B (red)
Look at the attached image

Both can change positions (coordinates, X & Y).
B has fixed dimensions (width & height), always known.
A's dimension can change, but they are always known.

I will always know the top and left coordinates of A & B (which can keep on changing) and can shift the rectangles to other quadrant.

Kindly look at the images below:

[image: Open image in new tab]

How do I determine whether more than 50% area of the red rectangle (B) is ***inside*** the black rectangle (A)?

I understand that (**area of B intersected by A**) *divided by* **Area of A** should be > **0.5**. How do I take care of the coordinate system within 2000, 2000, and cases where A might be too small to fit B?